# Ajuda com ERRO mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Tags: php

Olá, sou novo na programação em PHP e estou convivendo com este erro no meu script.

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\adm\Model\connectDB.php on line 30
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\adm\Model\user.class.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined variable: arr in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\adm\Model\user.class.php on line 51
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in 
  C:\xampp\htdocs\teste\adm\View\user.php on line 279
```

meu código

```
<?php

class MySQLDB
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "teste";
    private $senha = "";
    private $base = "curso_online";

    public function mysqli__construct()
    {
        $this->db = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->senha, $this->base);
        if (!$this->db) {
            echo "Erro: " . mysqli_error();
            die();
        } elseif (mysqli_select_db($this->db, $this->base)) {
            echo "Erro: " . mysqli_error();
            die();
        }
        mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        mysqli_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
        mysqli_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
        mysqli_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
    }

    public function ExecuteQuery($query)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
        return mysqli_query($this->query);
    }

    public function close()
    {
        if (mysqli_close($this->db)) {
            $this->db = null;
        }
    }

    public function mysqli__destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }

}

?>
```

a outra página

```
<?php
    include('includes/auth.php');
    require('../Controller/controller.php');

    if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])){
        switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
            case "in":
                $cad = new Control();
                $cad->cadUser($_POST["nome"], $_POST["senha2"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["status"]);
            break;
            case "out":
                $cad = new Control();
                $cad->delUser($_GET["nu"]);
            break;
            case "edit":
                $cad = new Control();
                $cad->editUser($_POST["id"], $_POST["nome"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["status"]);
            break;
            case "edit_senha":
                $cad = new Control();
                $cad->passUser($_POST["id"], $_POST["senha"]);
            break;
        }
    }
?>
<?php   include('includes/head.php'); ?>
<body>
    <!--[if !IE]>start wrapper<![endif]-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--[if !IE]>start head<![endif]-->
        <div id="head">
            <? include('includes/header.php') ?>
            <div id="menus_wrapper">
                <div id="main_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="selected"><span><span>Home</span></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="online.php"><span><span>Curso-online</span></span></a></li>                        
                        <li><a href="simulado.php"><span><span>Simulado</span></span></a></li>                          
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="sec_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <?php
                        if(isset($_REQUEST['nu'])){
                        ?>  
                        <li><a href="user.php" class="sm5">Voltar</a></li>
                        <?php
                        }else{
                        ?>
                        <li><a href="index.php" class="sm5">Voltar</a></li>                     
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="page">
                <div class="inner">
                    <div class="section">
                        <!--[if !IE]>start title wrapper<![endif]-->
                        <div class="title_wrapper">
                            <h2>Usuários</h2>

                            <span class="title_wrapper_left"></span>
                            <span class="title_wrapper_right"></span>
                        </div>
                        <!--[if !IE]>end title wrapper<![endif]-->
                        <!--[if !IE]>start section content<![endif]-->
                        <div class="section_content">
                            <!--[if !IE]>start section content top<![endif]-->
                            <div class="sct">
                                <div class="sct_left">
                                    <div class="sct_right">
                                        <div class="sct_left">
                                            <div class="sct_right">
                                                <?php
                                                    if(isset($_GET['nu'])){
                                                    $c = new Control();
                                                    $arr = $c->Controle_user($_GET['nu']);
                                                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){

                                                ?>
                                                <h3>Usuário do sistema: <?=$arr[$i]->nome['nome']?></h3>

                                                <form id="VI_User" action="user.php?action=edit" method="POST" class="search_form general_form">
                                                    <fieldset>
                                                        <div class="forms">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <label>Nome Completo:</label>
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                    <input name="id" id="id" type="hidden" value="<?=$arr[$i]->id['id']?>" />
                                                                    <span class="input_wrapper"><input class="text" name="nome" id="nome" type="text" value="<?=$arr[$i]->nome['nome']?>" title="Verifique o nome" /></span>
                                                                    <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <label>E-mail:</label>
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                    <span class="input_wrapper"><input class="text" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="<?=$arr[$i]->email['email']?>" title="O email está incorreto. Verifique." /></span>
                                                                    <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="row">   
                                                                <label>Ativo:</label>                                                       
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                    <span class="input_wrapper blank">
                                                                        <select name="status" id="status">
                                                                            <option value="1" <?=$arr[$i]->status['status']?'selected':''?>>Sim</option>
                                                                            <option value="0" <?=!$arr[$i]->status['status']?'selected':''?>>Não</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                </div>      
                                                            </div>                                                              
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="buttons">
                                                                    <ul>
                                                                        <li><span class="button send_form_btn"><span><span>Atualizar</span></span><input name="" type="submit" /></span></li>
                                                                        <li><span class="button send_form_btn"><a class="inline" href="#inline_content" style="color: white;"><span><span>Alterar senha</span></span></a></span></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                </form>
                                                <div style='display:none'>
                                                    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
                                                        <form id="User_SENHA" action="user.php?action=edit_senha" method="POST" class="search_form general_form">
                                                            <fieldset>
                                                                <div class="forms">
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <label>Senha:</label>
                                                                        <div class="inputs">
                                                                            <span class="input_wrapper"><input class="text" name="senha" id="senha" class="password_test" onkeyup="passwordStrength(this.value)" type="password" title="Verifique a senha" /></span>
                                                                            <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <p>
                                                                            <label for="passwordStrength">Password strength</label>
                                                                            <div id="passwordDescription">Password not entered</div>
                                                                            <div id="passwordStrength" class="strength0"></div>
                                                                        </p>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <label>Repita a senha:</label>
                                                                        <div class="inputs">
                                                                            <span class="input_wrapper"><input name="id" value="<?=$arr[$i]->id['id']?>" type="hidden" /><input class="text" name="senha1" id="senha1" type="password" title="As senhas tem que ser iguais." /></span>
                                                                            <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div class="row">
                                                                        <div class="buttons">
                                                                            <ul>
                                                                                <li><span class="button send_form_btn"><span><span>Editar</span></span><input name="" type="submit" /></span></li>
                                                                            </ul>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </fieldset>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php
                                                    }
                                                    }else{
                                                ?>
                                                <h3>Cadastrar novo usuário do sistema</h3>

                                                <form id="User" action="user.php?action=in" method="POST" class="search_form general_form">
                                                    <fieldset>
                                                        <div class="forms">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <label>Nome Completo:</label>
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                    <span class="input_wrapper"><input class="text" name="nome" id="nome" type="text" title="Verifique o nome" /></span>
                                                                    <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <label>E-mail:</label>
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                    <span class="input_wrapper"><input class="text" id="email" name="email" type="text" title="O email está incorreto. Verifique." /></span>
                                                                    <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <label>Senha:</label>
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                    <span class="input_wrapper"><input class="text" id="senha2" name="senha2" type="password" onkeyup="passwordStrength(this.value)" title="Senha inválida. Tente uma nova senha." /></span>
                                                                    <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <p>
                                                                    <label for="passwordStrength">Password strength</label>
                                                                    <div id="passwordDescription">Password not entered</div>
                                                                    <div id="passwordStrength" class="strength0"></div>
                                                                </p>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <label>Repita a senha:</label>
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                    <span class="input_wrapper"><input class="text" id="senha3" name="senha3" type="password" title="As senhas devem ser iguais." /></span>
                                                                    <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="row">   
                                                                <label>Ativo:</label>                                                       
                                                                <div class="inputs">
                                                                    <span class="input_wrapper blank">
                                                                        <select name="status" id="status">
                                                                            <option value="" selected>---</option>
                                                                            <option value="1">Sim</option>
                                                                            <option value="0">Não</option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </span>
                                                                    <span class="system negative"></span>
                                                                </div>      
                                                            </div>                                                      
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="buttons">
                                                                    <ul>
                                                                        <li><span class="button send_form_btn"><span><span>Cadastrar</span></span><input name="" type="submit" /></span></li>
                                                                        <li><span class="button cancel_btn"><span><span>Limpar</span></span><input name="" type="reset" /></span></li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </fieldset>
                                                </form>
                                                <?php
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                                <?php include('includes/alerta.php'); ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="scb"><span class="scb_left"></span><span class="scb_right"></span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section table_section">
                        <div class="title_wrapper">
                            <h2>Usuários cadastrados</h2>
                            <span class="title_wrapper_left"></span>
                            <span class="title_wrapper_right"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="section_content">
                            <div class="sct">
                                <div class="sct_left">
                                    <div class="sct_right">
                                        <div class="sct_left">
                                            <div class="sct_right">

                                                <form action="#">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                <!--[if !IE]>start table_wrapper<![endif]-->
                                                <div class="table_wrapper">
                                                    <div class="table_wrapper_inner">
                                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" width="100%">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th><a href="#" class="asc">ID#</a></th>
                                                                    <th><a href="#" class="desc">Nome completo</a></th>
                                                                    <th><a href="#">Email</a></th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 96px;">A&ccedil;ões</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <?php
                                                                define('TABLE1', 'odd gradeA');
                                                                define('TABLE2', 'odd gradeB');
                                                                $c = new Control();
                                                                $arr = $c->Controle_user($id = null);
                                                                for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){

                                                                ?>
                                                                <tr class="<? if($i % 2){ echo TABLE1; }else{ echo TABLE2; }?>">
                                                                    <td><?=$arr[$i]->id['id']?></td>
                                                                    <td><?=$arr[$i]->nome['nome']?></td>
                                                                    <td class="center"><?=$arr[$i]->email['email']?></td>
                                                                    <td class="actions">
                                                                        <ul>
                                                                            <li><a class="action2" href="user.php?nu=<?=$arr[$i]->id['id']?>">2</a></li>
                                                                            <li><a class="action4" href="user.php?action=out&nu=<?=$arr[$i]->id['id']?>" onClick="return confirm('Deletar o usuário <?=$arr[$i]->nome['nome']; ?> ?')">4</a></li>
                                                                        </ul>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <?php
                                                                }
                                                                ?>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                            <tfoot>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <th><a href="#" class="asc">ID#</a></th>
                                                                    <th><a href="#" class="desc">Nome completo</a></th>
                                                                    <th><a href="#">Email</a></th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 96px;">A&ccedil;ões</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tfoot>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="table_menu">
                                                </div>
                                                <!--[if !IE]>end table menu<![endif]-->


                                                </fieldset>
                                                </form>


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if !IE]>end section content top<![endif]-->
                            <!--[if !IE]>start section content bottom<![endif]-->
                            <span class="scb"><span class="scb_left"></span><span class="scb_right"></span></span>
                            <!--[if !IE]>end section content bottom<![endif]-->

                        </div>
                        <!--[if !IE]>end section content<![endif]-->
                    </div>
                    <!--[if !IE]>end section<![endif]-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--[if !IE]>end page<![endif]-->
            <!--[if !IE]>start sidebar<![endif]-->
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="inner">                             
                    <?php //include('includes/info_user.php'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta resposta está limitada ao erro:

> "*mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in [...]*"

---

Dando uma rápida olhada na documentação do `mysqli_query()`, verificamos a seguinte sintaxe:

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] ) : mixed
```

Como **o próprio erro já diz**, esta função espera pelo menos 2 parâmetros, e apenas 1 foi definido.

No seu caso, você passou a *query*, representada por `string $query` na sintaxe, mas não passou a conexão, representada por `mysqli $link` na sintaxe. Perceba:

```
// [...]
    $this->query = $query;
    return mysqli_query($this->query);
}
// [...]
```

**Solução:**

Considerando que você chame o método `mysqli__construct()` antes deste da query, basta você adicionar um argumento na chamada do `mysqli_query` com a conexão criada no `mysqli_construct()`:

```
// [...]
    $this->query = $query;
    return mysqli_query($this->db, $this->query);
}
// [...]
```

> Leitura recomendada: [PHP: mysqli::query](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php)

---

<strike>Não vou abordar os demais erros no seu código porque tornam a pergunta ampla. E [creio que] não é esse o objetivo do site. Corrigindo este, outros serão corrigidos com o retorno correto deste método. Caso reste dúvidas **referentes a outros erros** e, após algum esforço, você não tenha conseguido resolver, faça uma nova pergunta.</strike>